# In the ROUGE metrics, what do the low, mid and high values mean?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science, evaluation, summarization

The ROUGE metrics were introduced to "automatically determine the quality of a summary by comparing it to other (ideal) summaries created by humans" [[1](https://aclanthology.org/W04-1013.pdf)].

When calculating any ROUGE metric you get an `AggregateScore` object with 3 parameters: `low`, `mid`, `high`.
How are these aggregate values calculated?

For example, from the huggingface implementation [[2](https://huggingface.co/spaces/evaluate-metric/rouge)]:

```
>>> rouge = evaluate.load('rouge')
>>> predictions = ["hello there", "general kenobi"]
>>> references = ["hello there", "general kenobi"]
>>> results = rouge.compute(predictions=predictions,
...                         references=references)
>>> print(list(results.keys()))
['rouge1', 'rouge2', 'rougeL', 'rougeLsum']
>>> print(results["rouge1"])
AggregateScore(low=Score(precision=1.0, recall=1.0, fmeasure=1.0), mid=Score(precision=1.0, recall=1.0, fmeasure=1.0), high=Score(precision=1.0, recall=1.0, fmeasure=1.0))
>>> print(results["rouge1"].mid.fmeasure)
1.0
```

---

Edit: On July 7th, the huggingface  implementation was simplified to return a cleaner and easier to understand dict: https://github.com/huggingface/evaluate/issues/148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a list of (summary, gold_summary) pairs, any ROUGE metric is calculated per each item in the list. In huggingface, you can opt-out of the aggregation part by adding  `use_aggregator=False` and get these values returned.

For the aggregation, a bootstrap resampling is used [[1](https://aclanthology.org/W04-1013.pdf), [2](https://github.com/huggingface/evaluate/blob/f6e6f96ebcda074bbbaaff5ce5493eacfde096e7/metrics/rouge/rouge.py#L113)]. Bootstrap resampling is a technique used to extract confidence intervals [[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)), [4](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/478efa18a3a1fef144fac03fcd034829f348794e/rouge/scoring.py#L133)]. The idea is that for `n` samples, you draw `x` times a sample with replacement of size `n`, and then calculate some statistic for each resample. Now you get a new distribution called the `empirical bootstrap distribution`, which can be used to extract confidence intervals.

In the ROUGE implementation by google [[4](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/blob/478efa18a3a1fef144fac03fcd034829f348794e/rouge/scoring.py#L133)], they used:

- `n` for the number of resamples to run
- `mean` for the resample statistic
- `2.5th, 50th and 97.5th percentiles` to calculate the values for low, mid and high, respectively (can be controlled with the `confidence_interval` param)

### Randomness in ROUGE

Note that due to the bootstrapping technique used in ROUGE, it is non-deterministic, and can return different results for each run (see [[5](https://github.com/huggingface/evaluate/issues/186)]). If you don't want to opt out from using the bootstrapping technique, you can set the seed in the load function, as such: `evaluate.load('rouge', seed=42)`.